# How to count unanswered threads mysql/eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi I have table `threads` and `questions` with relation one-to-many.
every message has foreign key thread_id.
I want to check is last message in the thread is from user and if yes then count it, so it will count all unanswered threads by admin.

```
+----+-------------+---------+----------+------+
| id | thread_id   | user_id | admin_id | text |
|  1 |           1 |       1 |     NULL | test |
|  2 |           1 |       1 |     NULL | test |
|  3 |           1 |       1 |     NULL | test |
|  4 |           1 |       1 |     NULL | test |
+----+-------------+---------+----------+------+
```

The result from this dataset should be `1`, because all mesages belongs to the same thread and there is no admin answer (**last row has admin_id = NULL**).

I tried this:

```php
ThreadMessage::where('admin_id', '=', null)->groupBy('thread_id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(1)->count();
```

Sadly this just counts all the messages where admin_id is null, not just the last ones in thread.
The answer can be in mysql OR laravel eloquent. Thank you very much.

Comment: GROUP BY is excess. You need sort, take one (last) row then look its content and return the result depends on the value is NULL or not. PS. You cannot compare with NULL using `=`, this will always result to FALSE, you must use speciat `column IS [NOT] NULL` operator.

Comment: Thank you for advice, i am still learning

Answer (score 2):

To check for null you need to use `IS NULL` not `= NULL` operator. Use `whereNull()` method

```
ThreadMessage::whereNull('admin_id')->groupBy('thread_id')->count();
```

**EDIT**

To check if the last id is reponded to by admin, you can do it in two ways

- with code

```php
$thread = ThreadMessage::orderBy('thread_id', 'desc')->groupBy('thread_id')->first();
$answeredByAdmin = $thread->admin_id != null;
```

- With query (assuming the table name is `thread_messages`)

```
ThreadMessage:::whereNull('admin_id')
    ->groupBy('thread_id')
    ->whereIn('id', \DB::raw('(SELECT MAX(id) FROM thread_messages GROUP BY question_id)'))
    ->count();
```

Comment: thank you for advice but the code still counts all rows, not just the last one in thread

Comment: @PHPisMyPassion how do you differenciate the last thread from the ones before it ?

Comment: i am not sure if i understood you correctly but you can tell the thread is diffrent, bacause every message has thread_id column. So it would be something like get biggest message id (so we know it is the last sended message) from every thread, then check is admin_id is null and then count it. I don't know how to do this though

Comment: Your query from edited answer returns 16 instead of 1

Comment: altrough the query with bool checking works

Comment: I think this query have to be used to get biggest message id from each thread, and then check in loop is this message.id has admin_id NULL 
`select MAX(id) FROM thread_messages GROUP BY thread_id`

Comment: this works: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thread_messages WHERE id in (SELECT MAX(id) FROM thread_messages GROUP BY question_id) AND admin_id IS NULL` do you know how can I make it eloquent? thanks for help